# Get environment shell

Tags: java, shell, environment

I'm creating a Java library as the backend for a Tomcat web interface. The purpose of the library is to take arguments from the interface and use them to execute other commands on the system.

I know I can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to send the command, but is there a way to identify what shell the commands are sent to?

I'd like to use syntax I know from BASH to direct `stdout` to a target file, but I'm not sure if I'm in BASH, Bourne, or something else unique to the Java runtime.

Desired result: Shell flexibility. Detect when I can do

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand + " >> " + myTargetFile);`

and when that would be an invalid operator.

EDIT: formatting

Comment: You can exec the desired shell with the command. A search will deliver numerous examples. Runtime or especially ProcessBuilder are not difficult however.

Comment: As in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash " + myCommand)` ?

Comment: And, BTW, executing "command >> file" will not work from Java. >> is a shell redirect, so unless you're specifically creating a shell it will be treated as a program argument. Many other stackoverflow questions address this point and how to handle it.

Comment: Take a look at `System.getProperty("os.name")`